# How can I selectively suppress certain error messages that follow a certain pattern?

Tags: python, console, message

I have a Python program running a thread that consistently outputs the following:

```
(my_program.py:12313): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_output_stream_write: assertion `buffer != NULL' failed
```

This prints continuously, with no obvious detrimental effect on my program. For debugging purposes, I would like to suppress this particular line without suppressing other error messages. In other words, running:

```
my_computer:~$ python my_program.py 2>/dev/null
```

certainly works, but it also suppresses other useful error messages.

Ideally, of course, I would address the root cause and try to eliminate this error message, but in the meantime, is there a way to selectively not display this error message?

Comment: Just fix the cause. Will be easier and cleaner than whatever hackery and black magic is required to do so (edit: actually thinking of it, it might be a bash oneliner, but even then skipping the "meantime" part is best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
 python my_program.py 2>&1| grep -v "GLib-GIO-CRITICAL"
```

Comment: Use `python my_program.py 2>&1 |  grep -v "GLib-GIO-CRITICAL"`

Comment: Note that this combines stderr and stdout to be the new stdout, which is then piped to grep (to filter out lines containing the string to ignore).  It would be nice if you could redirect/pipe only stderr but most shells do not seem to support this.  (You can swap stderr and stdout if you don't want to merge them and pipe the stderr now in stdout, and redirect stdout somewhere else.)   Also, in some shells you also can get away with the syntax `python my_program.py |& grep -v "GLib-GIO-CRITICAL"` which is equivalent.

Comment: If you post that as an answer (with the snippet you suggested), I'll vote for it and delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a warning from GTK, are you using it? I don't think you can suppress them from Python.

Comment: Yes, it's a warning from GTK, but I'm looking to suppress it in the console at run time.